Adding entities to In Memory Database not working EF Core .NET 8
I have an in memory data set in EF Core for .NET 8 along with the method below for saving entities into the context
public static async Task SaveDataToEntitySetAsync<TEntity>(DbContext context, List<TEntity> list) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    if (list.Any())
    {
        var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        var nonNulls = list.Where(x => x != null);

        if(list.Any(x=>x== null))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Null Detected: {list.GetType().Name}");
        }

        foreach (var item in nonNulls)
        {
            dbSet.Add(item);
        
        }

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

This code worked fine in .NET Core 3.1 but in .NET 8 there are no errors but nothing gets saved into the Db context
Has anyone seen this?
Paul

The in-memory database works, EF Core 3.1 went out of support a long time ago and everyone's been using EF Core 5, 6,7 and now 8. The code itself suggests some serious design issues though. A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit-of-Work and SaveChanges persists all pending changes in a single transaction. Your method can perform 37 UPDATEs and 72 DELETEs. Using .Set<> doesn't make your code generic because the DbContext is not a connection and only works because it already contains the configuration for whatever concrete entity you used

BTW you can replace all this code with context.Customers.AddRange(customers.Where(c=>c!=null));. This will attach all Customer objects and their relations in the Added state. Only call SaveChanges when you want to commit the Unit-of-Work

Regardless of the design flaws etc what are my options here?

No repro with this plain vanilla fiddle. There's no provider problem to fix. I suspect the convoluted code ends up not persisting the data, storing it to the wrong context or reading the wrong context. Perhaps the input list is empty, or contains just nulls

Using  context.AddRange(newBlogs);, context.Blogs.AddRange(newBlogs); and context.Set<Blog>().AddRange(newBlogs); all work, so this isn't due to any differences on how DbSets work.

Using the in-memory database provider is strongly discouraged by EF.

@GertArnold the in-memory provider is very basic but just adding items isn't broken. Whatever prevents Add from working will prevent any other provider from working. The OP hasn't demonstrated any problem yet and the question's code adds items just like context.AddRange(blogs); context.SaveChanges();

@GertArnold the only "surprise" I encountered was adding the same 2 blog objects both with context.AddRange and the question's code without an explicit SaveChanges before. As the same instances were added in both cases, context.Blogs only contained 2 items afterwards. Any provider would be have the same

try to add the code: EnableSensitiveDataLogging()                   .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information); and  foreach (var entity in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())      {          Console.WriteLine($"Entity {entity.Entity.GetType().Name} is in state {entity.State}");      } to track the chnages

i have tried your provided code and it doesn't seem the problem you are facing is related to the shared code. There might be a misconfiguration or difference in how the DbContext is being set up in your project when migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 8. EF Core 8 which could have affected your setup.it would be great if you provide some reproducible sample with us.
